# I want to send FormData and an ID parameter together from React and handle them as ID and stream in C#

Tags: c#, reactjs, axios, multipartform-data

I am receiving a System.ArgumentNullException error when trying to send formData and messageId together using Axios, specifically when parsing the incoming stream with var parser = MultipartFormDataParser.Parse(incoming, Encoding.UTF8);. However, when I only send formData without the messageId, it works fine without errors

I am receiving a System.ArgumentNullException error when trying to send formData and messageId together using Axios, specifically when parsing the incoming stream with var parser = MultipartFormDataParser.Parse(incoming, Encoding.UTF8);. However, when I only send formData without the messageId, it works fine without errors. But I also need the messageId. How can I overcome this issue?
I am sharing the working version of the code below.

```
hubConnection.invoke("SendMessage", toUser?.UserId, textMessage,  repliedMessage?.id ?? null )
                .then((messageId) => {
                    console.log("Message ID:", messageId);
                   
                    selectedFiles.forEach((file, index) => {
                        formData.append(`file${index}`, file);
                    });           
                    if (selectedFiles && messageId) {
                        axios.post(`http://localhost:8220/api/Chat/UploadFile`, formData, {
                            headers: {
                                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
                                "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
                                // "Message-Id": messageId
                            }
                        }).then((response) => {
                        }).catch((error) => {
                        });
                    }
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.error("", error);
                });
```

C#:

```
public async Task UploadFile(Stream incoming)
    {
        var parser = MultipartFormDataParser.Parse(incoming, Encoding.UTF8);
        if (parser.Parameters.Count == 0 && parser.Files.Count == 0) throw new Exception("Stream Error");
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost("UploadFile")]
        [SwaggerResponse(200, "return", typeof(OkResult))]
        [SwaggerOperation(Summary = "Setting Dashboard User Configurations", Description = "Upload File")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile()
        {
            var obj = Request.Body;
            await _chatBusiness.UploadFile(obj);
            return Ok();
        }
```

The non-working version is as follows:

```
hubConnection.invoke("SendMessage", toUser?.UserId, textMessage,  repliedMessage?.id ?? null )
                .then((messageId) => {
                    console.log("Message ID:", messageId);
                 
                    selectedFiles.forEach((file, index) => {
                        formData.append(`file${index}`, file);
                    });           
                    if (selectedFiles && messageId) {
                        axios.post(`http://localhost:8220/api/Chat/UploadFile`, formData, {
                            headers: {
                                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
                                "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
                                "Message-Id": messageId
                            }
                        }).then((response) => {
                        }).catch((error) => {
                        });
                    }
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.error("Mesaj gönderirken hata oluştu", error);
                });
```

c#

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile([FromHeader] Guid messageId)
        {
            var obj = Request.Body;
            await _chatBusiness.UploadFile(obj, messageId);
            return Ok();
        }
```

```
  public async Task UploadFile(Stream incoming, Guid messageId)
    {
        var parser = MultipartFormDataParser.Parse(incoming, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: You are passing in "Message-Id" in your axios header, but the UploadFile method is looking for a "messageId".

Comment: MultipartFormDataParser.Parse does not work as you mentioned